# Are animations with ng-style possible? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-transitions

I have a div set to a dynamic height called `option.height` using AngularJS's ng-style attribute.

```
<div class="rec" ng-style="{ 'height': option.height, 'background-color': option.color}"></div>
```

When the page is loaded, the height may be set to anything from 0px to 300px, depending on earlier user input. While this works, I want the div height to animate from 0px to whatever value option.height is using CSS animations, instead of just starting at the correct height. Is this possible? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS `keyframes` with the `from` property.
This will animate it to the specified height from `0px`.

Something like:

```
@keyframes AnimHeight{
  from{
    height:0px;
  }
}
```

Example:

```css
.res {
  animation: AnimHeight 0.5s ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimHeight {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimHeight {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes AnimHeight {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes AnimHeight {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="res" style="height:100px;background:red;width:100%;">
</div>
```

**EDIT** : Added all the vendor specifics for `keyframes`.